# How to fix sonar "Make sure that hashing data is safe here" security issue

Tags: java, sonarqube, md5

After running the sonar Qube following security issue shown for this code snippet.

[image]

```
public String createToken(String text) {
        StringBuilder token = new StringBuilder(32);

        try {
            do {
                token.setLength(0);
                MessageDigest md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
                byte buffer[] = md.digest((text + random.nextInt()).getBytes());
                for (int index = 0; index < buffer.length; index++) {
                    if (((int) buffer[index] & 0xff) < 0x10) {
                        token.append("0");
                    }
                    token.append(Integer.toString(((int) buffer[index] & 0xff), 16));
                }
            } while (isTestingToken(token.toString()));
        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException nsae) {
            logger.error(nsae.getMessage());
        }
        return token.toString();
    }
```

how to fix this security issue.

Comment: MD5 is not secure. If you need secure token use secure alg, like SHA-256. https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/RSPEC-4790

Comment: @just Even SHA1 is not considered secure. But what if I don't need special security here? How to get rid of this warning?
Currently I'm generating a GUID based on some source data, let's say for comparison, like a checksum, but here I need a GUID as output.

Comment: @CLS in this case, you can mark this issue as "false positive" in sonarqube.